# Upgrading chaincode in hyperledger fabric gives no errors, but doesn't reflect changes

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm trying to update a chaincode with a 3 nodes blockchain using Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.4,  raft and multi ordering.

I'm using ansible to deploy the BC : https://github.com/Altoros/Ansible-Fabric-Starter

What I'm trying to do is upgrading the chaincode.

I first log in the cli container in a node:

```
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-46-199:~$ docker exec -it cli.org0.domain bash 

 root@56e6868e66a0:/etc/hyperledger/artifacts# export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org0.domain:7051 && peer chaincode install -n main -v 1.0.1 -p  main  -l golang
2021-03-18 16:54:45.475 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2021-03-18 16:54:45.475 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
2021-03-18 16:54:47.599 UTC [chaincodeCmd] install -> INFO 003 Installed remotely response:<status:200 payload:"OK" > 

 root@56e6868e66a0:/etc/hyperledger/artifacts# export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org0.domain:7051 && peer chaincode upgrade -n main -v 1.0.1 -c "{\"Args\":[\"GetMeasuresBetween\",\"2019-03-29T12:00:00Z\", \"2019-03-29T14:00:00Z\"]}" -o orderer2.domain:7050 -C org0 --tls --cafile /etc/hyperledger/artifacts/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/domain/tlsca/tlsca.domain-cert.pem
2021-03-18 17:03:09.896 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2021-03-18 17:03:09.897 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
```

Everything seems to be working.

But when I try to invoke the chaincode where I changed a debug message

```
peer chaincode invoke --cafile /etc/hyperledger/artifacts/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/domain/tlsca/tlsca.domain-cert.pem --tls -o orderer2.domain:7050 -C org0 -n main -c "{\"Args\":[\"AddMeasure\",\"ACC00000000\",\"23547901584620111112\",\"Conso\",\"BASE\",\"1010\",\"2019-11-01T08:30:01Z\"]}"
```

it is also working well, but I cannot see in the logs the new debug message, only seeing old one.

Is it something I am missing ? When invoking the chaincode, will it always take the latest version ?

Answer (score 0):

After you install the new version on each peer, you need to then perform an upgrade operation (analogous to doing install and instantiate when you deployed the initial version of the chaincode).